# ¿Como convertir una fecha que esta en formato String a tipo Date en Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, string, date, date-format

El asunto es que tengo muchas fechas que están en formato String en java, las fechas son todas así: **"Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 CST 2004"**, las fechas cambian pero se ven todas así, ¿Como podria pasarla a tipo Date/Fecha para que se puedan almacenar en una tabla de base de datos(Postgresql)?, no se necesita poner en un formato en especifico pero si es necesario no hay inconveniente, solo cambiarla a tipo Date, e intentado de muchas formas pero aun no logro parsearla, ¿Alguna sugerencia?, gracias.

Anexo un ejemplo de un ejemplo de codigo con el cual intente parsear la fecha(solo puse una fecha en tipo String aunque son muchos, pero como dije todas las fechas se ven similares, no cambia su estructura):

```
    String fecha = "Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 CST 2004";
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime trueDate = null;

    
    try {
        String newFecha = myFormatObj.format(trueDate);
        trueDate.format(myFormatObj);
        System.out.println("Fecha en tipo date: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se a podido convertir la fecha a tipo date: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás usando `format` dos veces y además, intentando formatear `trueDate` sin ser una fecha válida.

Simplemente necesitas:

1. Obtener un objeto `LocalDateTime` de tu cadena de fecha mediante el método `pattern()`, indicándole el patrón en que está esa cadena, que para tu caso sería este: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. Para determinar el patrón de cualquier fecha consulta el significado de cada letra en el apartado [***Pattern Letters and Symbols*** de la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).
2. **Si fuera necesario**<sup>1</sup>, crear la cadena de fecha indicándole de nuevo el patrón en el que quieres que dicha cadena sea formateada. En este caso, para insertar en la base de datos el patrón habitual para columnas del tipo `DATETIME` es: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
 String fecha = "Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 CST 2004";   
    
 try 
 {   
     LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse(fecha, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"));
     String dateString=d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
     System.out.println(dateString);
 
  } 
  catch (DateTimeParseException e) 
  {     
     System.out.println("No se a podido convertir la fecha a tipo date: " + e.getMessage());         
  }
```

**Salida:**

```
2004-03-16 00:00:00
```

---

#### Notas

1. A partir de JDBC 4.2 tú puedes usar objetos de la API `time` para insertarlos en la base de datos. En ese caso no necesitarías crear una cadena con la fecha, sino simplemente usar el objeto `d` que estamos creando. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039615/5587982) en SO en inglés.

Comment: Me genero el siguiente error: No se a podido convertir la fecha a tipo date: Text 'Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 CST 2004' could not be parsed at index 0, importe las librerias java.time

Comment: @UsielGarciaJimenez edita la pregunta poniendo la nueva versión del código, incluyendo los `import.` Lo he probado con la cadena tal cual está en mi respuesta y la salida es la que se muestra al final. Si estás leyendo las fechas de un archivo o de otra fuente considera limpiar los datos de espacios en blanco que podrían estar rodando, así como dobles espacios en blanco y cosas por el estilo.